# Python: comparing and replacing list[i] with brackets

Tags: python, string, list, replace

Given two lists, I want to compare list1 and list2, and replace it within list1, and add brackets.

```
str1 = "red man juice"
str2 = "the red man drank the juice"

one_lst = ['red','man','juice']
lst1 = ['the','red','man','drank','the','juice']
```

expected output:

```
lst1 = ['the','[red]','[man]','drank','the','[juice]']
```

What I tried so far:

```
lst1 = list(str1.split())
for i in range(0,len(lst1)):
    for j in range(0,len(one_lst)):
        if one_lst[j] == lst1[i]:
            str1 = str1.replace(lst1[i],'{}').format(*one_lst)
lst1 = list(str1.split())
print(lst1)
```

I'm able to replace it, but just without brackets.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: do you have to check for order? what would the result be if `str1` was `"man juice red"`?

Comment: it'll always be in chronological order via the main str.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is what you would do in a lower-level language. Unless you have a specific need for this, in Python, I would instead use a `list` comprehension:

```py
str1 = 'red man juice'
str2 = 'the red man drank the juice'

words_to_enclose = set(str1.split())

result = [f'[{word}]'  # replace with '[{}]'.format(word) for Python <= 3.5
          if word in words_to_enclose 
          else word 
          for word in str2.split()]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['the', '[red]', '[man]', 'drank', 'the', '[juice]']
```

The benefit of conversion to a `set` is that it takes (roughly) the same time to check if a `set` contains something regardless of how large it is, whereas the time taken for the same operation for a `list` scales with its size.

Comment: I would simply add that *f-strings* are Python 3.6+. OP might not be as up-to-date. Otherwise, +1

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 = 'red man juice'
str2 = 'the red man drank the juice'

one_lst = ['red','man','juice']
lst1 = ['the','red','man','drank','the','juice']

res=[]

for i in lst1:
    if i in one_lst:
        res.append('{}{}{}'.format('[',i,']'))
    else:
        res.append(i)

print(res)
```

output

```
['the', '[red]', '[man]', 'drank', 'the', '[juice]']
```

Comment: Why not `'[{}]'`?

Comment: @gmds it can be use, that mentioned way come first in mind so i wrote it

Comment: Hey, this solution is working, but i'm getting this output:
['t','h',' ','[','r','e','d',']',' ',etc...

Comment: @swamz can you please provide input ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner suggestion:

```
[x if x not in str1.split(' ') else [x] for x in str2.split(' ')]
```

**Output**

> ['the', ['red'], ['man'], 'drank', 'the', ['juice']]